# Regular expression same pattern only applies to 1 result

Tags: python, regex

I want to find several `tags` in a webpage using regular expression, they have the same pattern: `data-tag-slug="NAME"`, like this(only a small section):

```
...category="rating" data-tag-id="40482" data-tag-name="safe" data-tag-slug="safe"><a cla...
...category="" data-tag-id="42350" data-tag-name="solo" data-tag-slug="solo"><a cla...
```

And I coded `tagName = r'.*data-tag-slug="(\w+)".*'`, use `re.findall(tagName, html)`, yet I can only get one result, which is the very last item that fits the pattern. I wonder how can I get all of them.

P.S. By "the very last item", I mean that there're several tags that fit the pattern, but the code can only get the last one by the order of appearance in the html.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @G_M I know the existence of beautifulsoup, but re is generally faster when dealing with simple match, and I am going to deal with a million webpages, so I don't really want to use beautifulsoup

Comment: Sounds like you've got it all figured out.

Comment: Your regex matches the entire string if it matches at all.  Get rid of the `.*`s at both ends.

Comment: @jasonharper Didn't think it'll be so simple... thank you

Comment: @G_M No, I was told by several people or books that re is complex but fast while beautifulsoup is easy but slower. And I believe it is wiser to choose based on what I am going to do instead of simply seeking some " More Advanced" way

Comment: @AmarthGûl Faster than `lxml` which is written in C? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: @G_M I didn't see any sentences in your link that points out directly bs is faster than re. And since our conversation is becoming salty, I'll be honest and ask: Don't you feel rude if somebody says "Go eat meat" when others are asking "How to cook bread?"

Comment: @AmarthGûl https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8079103

Comment: @G_M I see you are the kind of "Highly educated" people who only speak with "Evidence", so which one I am supposed to listen?  `You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.` or `You totally can parse context-free grammars with regex`? Do you think you are cool judging me without knowing what I am doing? Must I use your Majesty's Majestic Suggestion when I know what I'm facing is totally safe for regex?

Comment: @AmarthGûl https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/8079103

Comment: @G_M open up your eye your Majesty. Please see the entire post instead of only the one answer that fits you.

Comment: @AmarthGûl https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the greedy `.*` from your regex:

```py
import re
txt = """category="rating" data-tag-id="40482" data-tag-name="safe" data-tag-slug="safe">category="" data-tag-id="42350" data-tag-name="solo" data-tag-slug="solo">"""
out = re.findall(r'data-tag-slug="(\w+)"', txt)
print(out)
#> ['safe', 'solo']
```

Created on 2018-10-02 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)

```py
import reprexpy
print(reprexpy.SessionInfo())
#> Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Platform: Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit (64-bit)
#> Python: 3.6
#> Date: 2018-10-02
#> Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> reprexpy==0.1.1
```